# OS X Folder contents not visible over LAN

Tags: mac, permissions

Two Mac systems connected via a LAN (ethernet + occasionally WiFi) running macOS 10.15.4. System A contains most of our files, system B is used when another user needs access. When I mount system A in system B's Finder window, I can see into and transfer to and from all folders on system A's Home directory except three, Desktop, Documents and Downloads. When I try to open the folders I get a 'you don't have permission...' message. Also the folder icons show up with a new (to me) down arrow inside a circle bottom right (not the alias icon). I have gone through Apple's procedure for resetting Home directory permissions via the recovery system but this did not help. I'm somewhat familiar with Unix / file permissions but not with Apple's complex(at least to me) permissions system. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You could probably do it with ACLs, unless Catalina stops you [I don't have access to Catalina to test]. On the Mac you mount remotely, Get Info on the specific folders & add perms for the user or group you want to permit access. Note this is not ideal, for security purposes.

Comment: Thanks, the name / privileges in visible and invisible folders are the same in the GetInfo windows. However, the ones that hide contents have a message "you have custom access"

Comment: It seems this a Catalina 'feature' that any app requiring access to these folders requires permission via SystemPrefs->Files and Folders. However no app is requesting it so I can't grant access in this way.

Comment: *"you have custom access"* tells me you are still accessing these folders **remotely**. You have to change perms from the source machine, not the remote.

Comment: Not at all, this is the source machine system A. It's a new feature in Catalina protecting these folders. I don't have the problem in reverse, I see that smbd and sshd have Full Disk access on system B but not A. I'm sure this is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is due to enhanced security for these particular folders in Catalina. It can be resolved by giving 'Full Disk Access' to smbd. Instead of using System Preferences->Security&Privacy->Privacy->Full Disk Access, open System Preferences->Sharing and turn off File Sharing then turn it on again. This will add smbd to the list of apps having Full Disk Access. Problem solved. I found this at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250716547